# exponential of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix in $M_n(\Bbb C)$ whose minimal polynomial is $(X-1)(X-2)$ 
Find $exp(A)$ .

what I tried to do, is to calculate $exp(A)$ by using the definition and separate the sum to odd and even index. and because we know that spectra of $A$ is ${1,2}$ we know also that the igenvalues of $exp(A)$ are $exp(1)$ and $exp(2)$ ,so I tried to show them in the sum .Anyway I couldn't find the final result .I hope that someone could help .

Comment: You need more information to find $e^A$. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ have the same minimal polynomial but different exponentials.

Comment: You will find the expression of $exp(A)$ depending on $A$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $A^n=a_nA+b_nI$, and introduce this in 
$$\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_kA+b_kI}{k!}=\cdots=A\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!} + I\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_k}{k!}$$ 
(be carefull, there may be some adjustment in this formula, for the first two terms don't follow the recurrence rule...).

So $\exp(A)$ is an affine function of $A$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

By Cayley-Hamilton

$0=(A-I)(A-2I)=(A-I)(A-I-I)=(A-I)^2-(A-I)$. With $B:=A-I$ we get $B^n=B$ for $n \ge 1$, hence

$\frac{1}{e}e^A=e^{B}=I+B \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=I+B(e-1)$. Therefore

$$a^A=eI+(e^2-e)B=eI+(e^2-e)(A-I)$$

Comment: Your answer is brilliant sir !

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* The minimal polynomial of $A$ is a product of distinct linear factors, so $A$ is diagonalisable and its eigenvalues are $1$ and $2$. Therefore, if $p(\lambda)$ is any polynomial such that $p(\lambda)=e^{\lambda}$ when $\lambda=1,2$, then $e^A=p(A)$.